# Not receiving pusher message

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, broadcasting

Hello i am using `laravel broadcasting` and `pusher` to send some info.
**I can successfully send message to pusher** *but* **cant receive that**.
Here is my codes, Please help me guys:(

App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    created() {
        Echo.private('gameRoom')
            .listen('RequestsEvent', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
});
```

Bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});
```

RequestsEvent.php

```
class RequestsEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $type;
    public $room_manager;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param $type
     * @param $room_manager
     */
    public function __construct($type, $room_manager)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->room_manager = $room_manager;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return PrivateChannel
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('gameRoom');
    }
}
```

Channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('gameRoom', function () {
    return true;
});
```

Html :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Listen</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I already installed `pusher` and `laravel echo` and I have following things in my `console` :

> Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development
>   experience: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools app.js:38040 
>   You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on production mode
>   when deploying for production. See more tips at
>   https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: this warning is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about `Vue`. I run `npm install vue` in cmd although i did that and every thing went ok.

Answer (score 0):

you should uncomment this provider in config/app.php file. like this

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```